# Restar variables antes insertar en PHP y MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

Quisiera restar 2 variables (PHP y MySQLi) al momento de insertar un registro en la base de datos. Voy a colocar el codigo a continuacion:

```
$fecha = isset($_POST['fecha']) ? $_POST['fecha'] : '';
$nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : '';
$direccion = isset($_POST['direccion']) ? $_POST['direccion'] : '';
$valor = isset($_POST['valor']) ? $_POST['valor'] : '';
$gastos = isset($_POST['gastos']) ? $_POST['gastos'] : '';
$ganancia = isset($_POST['ganancia']) ? $_POST['ganancia'] : '';
$insertar = "INSERT INTO tbl_compra (fecha, nombre, direccion, valor, gastos, ganancia) VALUES 
('$fecha','$nombre','$direccion','$valor','$gastos','$valor-$gastos') ";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
```

Ojala se entienda lo que estoy queriendo hacer

Saludos

Comment: No queda claro que problema tienes con ese código, por otro lado ¿por qué no ejecutas la resta antes y la asignas a una variable que posterior pases al `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema, como bien dice @BetaM, es que debes hacer el cálculo antes de la inserción. De lo contrario, estarías insertando algo como: `9999-99` en la tabla, pero no el resultado de la resta. Si haces un `echo $insertar;` podrás verlo.

Además, para valores numéricos, no hay que poner comillas simples en la instrucción SQL.

Así debería funcionar:

## Primero calculamos

```
$ganancia=$valor-$gastos;

$insertar = "INSERT INTO tbl_compra (fecha, nombre, direccion, valor, gastos, ganancia) VALUES 
('$fecha','$nombre','$direccion',$valor,$gastos,$ganancia)";
```

He quitado las comillas a las columnas que son numéricas.

### Advertencias

1. Considera blindar tu código, usando en este caso consultas preparadas. Actualmente tu programa es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.
2. No tiene demasiado sentido, para este caso, guardar campos calculados. Es mejor calcularlos in situ, cuando los necesites. Podrías estar creando un cementerio de datos en tu tabla para usarlos quien sabe cuando, o no usarlos nunca o muy poco.
3. Considera verificar que los eventuales datos con restricción `NOT NULL` en la tabla no están vacíos. En tu código actual, si el usuario no escribe el nombre por ejemplo, se estarían guardando nombres en blanco en la tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas. En las tablas tengo los campos con NOT NULL para que no ocurra lo que me dices. Muchas gracias por tu corrección también.

Comment: @max.ks OK, pero `NOT NULL` no evade este dato: `''` Sí, es un espacio en blanco lo que estás asignando en caso de que no se cumpla el `isset` y  **espacio en blanco no es lo mismo que `NULL`** por tanto, si mandas un espacio en blanco se insertará.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias